# Find minimum surface area of half cylinder given volume

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to build a half-cylinder structure, with the volume $1200$ cubic feet. But I want to find the minimum surface area needed to achieve this volume. I'm struggling.

I know that the equation for the surface area I'll need is

$A=\pi r^2+h\pi r.$

as well as the volume equation

$V=\pi r^2h/2.$

I'd like $r \geq 6.5$ ft.

Comment: Do you know how to find maxima using the first derivative?  By plugging in 1200 for V in the Volume equation, you can get $h$ or $r$ in terms of the other.  Then you can substitute that into the SA formula and have an equation of one variable, for which the maximum can be found via first derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach appears to use calculus, but we can also do it neatly using the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Solving for $h$ using the equation for volume, we get

$$h=\frac{2400}{\pi r^2}$$

and hence

$$A=\pi r^2+\frac{2400}{r}$$

Now, by the AM-GM inequality, we have

$$A=\pi r^2+\frac{1200}{r}+\frac{1200}{r}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\pi r^2\times\frac{1200}{r}\times\frac{1200}{r}}=3\sqrt[3]{1200^2\pi}\approx496$$
with equality when

$$\pi r^2=\frac{1200}{r}=\frac{1200}{r}$$
which occurs at
$$r=\sqrt[3]\frac{1200}{\pi}\approx 7.26$$

Hence the minimum surface area of $\approx 496 \text{ ft}^2$ is achieved when $r\approx 7.26\text{ ft}$.

By the way, if you want a calculus solution as well, I can include it since I wrote it up before I realized there was a nice way to go about it.